# Rotate label on secondary axis

Tags: pgfplots, labels

So, I want to have a plot with two y-axes - done. However, since the labels consist of only one symbol, I want them written horizontally. That is usually accomplished by rotate=-90. This works, but only on one side. How can I get it to the right orientation on the secondary axis?

Here a minmal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
t  percentage  absolute
.1  15     30      
.2  2     40     
.3  25     50      
.4  27.5     55     
.5  30     60      
.6  32     64
    }\datatable
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    scale only axis,
    width=0.85\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
axis x line=bottom
}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=64,
ylabel=$\Sigma$,ylabel style={rotate=-90},
axis y line=right,
    scaled ticks=true]
\addplot[only marks,red,mark=o] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=absolute]{\datatable}; \label{plot_one}
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[ymajorgrids,ymin=0,ymax=100,
xlabel=Subject no,
ylabel=$\%$,ylabel style={rotate=-90},
scaled ticks=true,
axis y line=left]
\addplot[only marks,green] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=percentage]{\datatable};
\addplot[tick=none] table[x expr=\coordindex, y={create col/linear regression={y=percentage}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Gives

[image: Note the rotated "%" but unaffected "Σ"]

Any suggestions on how to rotate the Σ as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
axis y line*=right,   % and axis y line* = left too
```

instead of `axis y line=right,` The starred version affects only the axis line leaving other things like positions of axis labels, tick lines etc. Since you are using `\pgfplotsset` inside the `tikzpicture` environment, it is better to add `ylabel style={rotate=-90},` in it. To remove arrows from axis use `axis line style={-},` in `\pgfplotsset`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotstableread{
t  percentage  absolute
.1  15     30
.2  2     40
.3  25     50
.4  27.5     55
.5  30     60
.6  32     64
    }\datatable
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    scale only axis,
    width=0.85\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
axis x line=bottom,
axis line style={-},          %% <--- here
ylabel style={rotate=-90},    %%<--- here
}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=64,
ylabel=$\Sigma$,
axis y line*=right,
    scaled ticks=true,
    ]
\addplot[only marks,red,mark=o] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=absolute]{\datatable}; \label{plot_one}
%\addlegendentry{Sum watched trials}
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[ymajorgrids,ymin=0,ymax=100,
xlabel=Subject no,
ylabel=$\%$,
%y unit label=$\%$,
scaled ticks=true,
axis y line*=left]
\addplot[only marks,green] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=percentage]{\datatable};
\addplot[tick=none] table[x expr=\coordindex, y={create col/linear regression={y=percentage}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You were on right way ... you need just add

```
 style={rotate=-90},
```

to the second `axis`, or even better, put it with other common parameters into `\pgfplotsset{...}` . If you add here `set layers`, you will obtain borders aroun image without arrows.

[image]

Slightly rearranged and simplified your code, which generate above image is:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,
               preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \pgfplotstableread{
    t  percentage  absolute
    .1  15     30
    .2  2     40
    .3  25     50
    .4  27.5     55
    .5  30     60
    .6  32     64
        }\datatable

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% let both axes use the same layers
    \pgfplotsset{set layers,
    ylabel style={rotate=-90},
        scaled ticks=true,
                }
\begin{axis}[
    ymajorgrids,
    ymin=0,  ymax=100,
    xlabel=Subject no,
    ylabel=$\%$,
    axis y line*=left]
\addplot[only marks,green] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=percentage]{\datatable};
\addplot[tick=none] table[x expr=\coordindex, y={create col/linear regression={y=percentage}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{\datatable};
\end{axis}
%
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,ymax=70,
    ylabel=$\Sigma$,
    axis y line*=right]
\addplot[only marks,red,mark=o] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=absolute]{\datatable}; \label{plot_one}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Edit: in the first attempt I misunderstand your question, as pointed Harish Kumar in his comment. Now I correct and add some small improvements to your code.